# Is there a way of enforcing a specific relation between weights and biases of an ANN during training?

Tags: tensorflow, networking, keras, constraints

I have a single perceptron (see figure) that I want to train it for a particular task, by means of keras.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbsC4.png)

Is there a simple way of enforcing a specific relation **between weights and bias**, during training? For instance, I want the following relation always to hold:

w1 + w2 + b < 0.

Of course, the aforementioned question applies, also, to more complex neural networks.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi..Can you please let us know the use case which requires this relation between Weights and Biases. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your interest! My aim (which I'm not sure if it is feasible) can be described as follows: I assume that prior knowledge can be, essentially, expressed as a relation between weights and biases. That is to say, if weights and biases take specific (known) values of some range, then the perceptron produces specific (known) outputs. Hence, I assume that, if I enforce a specific relation between weights and biases during training, I may have a quick training and, at the same time, the desired output of the network. In a sense, I inject prior knowledge in the network.